# React lazy load expensive material-ui modal

Tags: reactjs, optimization, material-ui

I have got expensive material-ui modal component that takes around 1s to render which I tried to lazy load with Suspense and React.lazy but it didn't work for me, if I understand it correctly it only lazy loads import (?)

About the modal component, there is no fetching from api or anything just many components with hooks and material-ui inside and data passed as props

The process that I have now:

1. I click button
2. *1s passes*
3. everything is loaded and modal opens

What I'm trying to accomplish"

1. I click button
2. Modal immediately pops up and shows some sort of loading screen
3. When component is ready it shows up

how can I do it in react?

Comment: This is usually something related to your other code that affects the performance. You can provide a codesandbox to show, it should be better and maybe you will find out the problem at that time.

Comment: I know that performance could be improved a little but it will still take some time to load since there are a lot of components inside that's why I wanted to know if what I stated in my question could be done, also my application is pretty big so I won't be able to provide codesandbox

Comment: It's okay. I can give you a keyword "useWorker" in React. Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a simple check in your modal component and render it conditionally. So suppose if your have three data the you can use ternary operator just below the return the data only if all data is loaded and if not then show a loading component
Sample code might make you clear what I'm trying to say. In my case the data was coming from an API so I put a check if that data is loaded or not.

```
   function ModalComponent(data1, data2, data3){
    
      /////// other code //////
        return (
        <div>
        {data1 && data2 && data3 ? (
           <div>Your data </div>
        ) : <div>Loading....</div>
        }
        </div>)
    }
export default ModalComponent
```